# Passing int using char pointer in C

Tags: c, exec, ipc

I'm trying to figure out how to pass an int using a char pointer. It fails once the int value is too large for the char. This is what I'm trying to figure out:

```
char *args[5];

int i = 20;

/*some other code/assignments*/

args[2] = (char *)&i;

execv(path, args);
```

How would I do something like this if i was a bigger value, like 400?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? Why are you passing an integer using a char pointer?

Comment: I think somewhere you are confusing numbers with representations of numbers. Are you really trying to pass the number twenty (the number of things you have if you have eighteen and someone gives you two more)? Or are you trying to pass the string "20" (a string consisting of the decimal digit '2' followed by the decimal digit '0')?

Comment: I'm trying to pass an integer to another program as an argument

Comment: But programs don't take integers as arguments. They take strings (which can represent numbers).

Comment: Well, I'm trying to pass dimensions of a matrix to another program using execv

Comment: Okay, so you're trying to pass strings to the program. And you're in luck because the C language uses char pointers for strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Programs simply do not take integers as arguments, they take strings. Those strings can be decimal representations of integers, but they are still strings. So you are asking how to do something that simply doesn't make any sense.

Twenty is an integer. It's the number of things you have if you have eighteen and then someone gives you two more. Twenty cannot be a parameter to an executable.

"20" is a string. It can represent the number twenty in decimal. But it's a sequence of two characters, the decimal digit '2' followed by the decimal digit '0'.

You pass strings to executables, not integers.

When you enter a command like `tail -f 20`, the number twenty is not one of the arguments. They are the string "tail", the string "-f", and the string "20" (the digit '2' followed by the digit '0'). There are no numbers in there, just strings (though one of them happens to represent a number).

You can do this:

```
int i = 10;
char parameter[32];
sprintf(parameter, "%d", i);
// parameter now contains the string "10"
args[2] = parameter;
```